# Cannot update database with EntityManager by using multithread socket

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm making an application for multiple client and 1 server socket, each client socket work on with a thread. When a client contact with other client and do something then both send request to server to update current user, and each thread responsible for each client will update to database by `UserService` class **at the same time**. This make transaction get the error.

```
public class UserService {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    EntityTransaction transaction;

    public UserService() {
        // turn off
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    }
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            entityManager.merge(user);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** thread class that controls a socket I have declared static `UserService`
if i don't use static class i get the following error `[SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)`

```
public class EchoThread extends Thread {
    protected Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in;
    BufferedWriter out;
    private static UserService userService = new UserService();;

    public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        line = in.readLine();
        // do something with current user

        userService.updateUser(user);

    }

}
```

Error

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at Services.UserService.updateUser(UserService.java:25)
    at Utils.EchoThread.run(EchoThread.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map$Entry.getValue()" because "me" is null
ERROR: HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible nonthreadsafe access to session
```

How i can update it

Comment: Entity manager is not thread safe. Each thread needs its own.

Comment: Thanks, In each thread i need create new ```UserService``` class instead of a static class, right ?

Comment: if i don't use static class i get the following error [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)

Comment: You need to share the `EntityManagerFactory`.